# Why does format() change numbers into characters?

Tags: r, format

Why does format change numbers into characters?  Is there a way to force format() to keep output as numeric? This becomes an issue for me when dealing with lists of dataframes.

```
> number <- 33333
> class(number)
[1] "numeric"
> test1 <- format (number, nsmall = 2 )
> class(test1)
[1] "character"
> test2 <- as.numeric (format (number, nsmall = 2 ))
> class(test2)
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: `format` turns numbers into characters. That's it's whole job. Formatting is a property of a string representation of a number.  Maybe you want `round()` in this case? But in R, numbers don't remember how many decimal places they have.

Comment: fair enough.  I was using the wrong function.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`formattable` can return `numeric` with additional formatting using `formatC`

```
test1 <- formattable::comma(number, digits=2, big.mark = "")
```

-checking

```
> class(test1)
[1] "formattable" "numeric"    
> test1
[1] 3333.00
> test1 + 10
[1] 3343.00
```

Comment: I just discovered another way to change the format without changing the numbers to characters.  It's using the options() function.

'number <- 33333.3333
class(number)
options(scipen=100, digits = 2)
number
class(number)'

Comment: @JamesR there are many ways.  But, I find `formattable` much helpful especially when we are trying to display tables in markdown etc